# DeviceEventEmitter.addListener Warning Cannot update during an existing state transition

Tags: react-native

When I add the device emitter below it throws the warning:

> Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as
>   within `render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props
>   and state.

```
componentDidMount() {
    DeviceEventEmitter.addListener('showFloater', (e) => {
        this.setState({showFloater:true})
    });

    DeviceEventEmitter.addListener('hideFloater', (e) => {
        this.setState({showFloater:false})
    });
}
```

Here is the constructor snippet:

```
this.state = {
        pan:new Animated.ValueXY(), 
        _value:{
            x: 0, 
            y: 0
        },
        showFloater: false
    };
```

Any ideas why I'm getting the warning?  Removing setState and it loads fine.

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it, if anyone else runs into this issue:

```
this.listner = DeviceEventEmitter.addListener('showFloater', (e) => {
        this.setState({showFloater:e.val})
    });
```